# Uso de la función strcat

Tags: c

Tengo una duda en lenguaje básico y no logro entender lo que dicen otras páginas mi duda radica en el código siguiente:

```
include<stdio.h>
include<stdlib.h>

void creacion(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int n,i;

        do{
            printf("Teclea el numero de archivos: ");
            scanf("%i" , & n);
        }while(n<1 || n>5);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        creacion(i);

}

void creacion (int num){
    FILE *file;

        fopen=strcat(num,".csv");//file(file,"at");



    fclose(file);       
}
```

Mi problema radica en que no sé usar la función `strcat`. No le encuentro una manera y quisiera saber de alguien que me dé un ejemplo simple para esto.

Comment: Tu duda básicamente es: "¿Cómo usar `strcat`?", ¿Por qué no empiezas leyendo la documentación?

Comment: básicamente si no logro entender en otras páginas y esto es nuevo para mi nose si puedas ofrecerme una ayuda, se que me falta string.h y hay algo que se me escapa

Comment: En [Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcat) hay algo así... Y tu código tiene varios problemas...

Comment: como cuales problemas detectas?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer sobre E/S estándar en C, manejo de punteros y funciones para manejar cadenas de texto. Entre los problemas más pesados uno es `fopen` es una función que devuelve un puntero a `FILE`, `strcat` necesita 2 punteros a `char` y haces `fclose` a algo que nunca abrió, en resumen, tu código no compila.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Answer (score 10):

> Mi problema radica en que no se usar la función `strcat`.

#### Lee el manual.

Normalmente la mejor solución para este tipo de dudas es leer documentación. Por desgracia, la documentación en Español es escasa, puedes consultar la traducción automática de cppreference:

- [`strcat`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat).

Pero la traducción suele ser confusa (siendo amables), así que permíteme compartir mi versión:

> La función [`strcat`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat):
>
> ```
> char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );
> ```
>
> Definida en la cabecera [`<string.h>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte), anexa una copia de la cadena de bytes con terminador nulo apuntada por `src` en el final de la cadena de bytes con terminador nulo apuntada por `dest`. El carácter `src[0]` substituye el terminador nulo en el final de `dest`. La cadena de bytes resultante contendrá terminador nulo.
>
> El comportamiento no está definido si el arreglo de destino no tiene suficiente espacio para contener tanto `src` como `dest` y el terminador nulo. El comportamiento no está definido si las dos cadenas se superponen. El comportamiento no está definido si tanto `dest` como `src` no son punteros a cadenas de bytes con terminador nulo.
>
> El valor de retorno es un puntero apuntando a la cadena de bytes con terminador nulo que contiene el resultado de la operación, es decir un puntero con el mismo valor que `dest`.

Esta descripción nos introduce un par de conceptos que tal vez te sean desconocidos:

- **Terminador nulo**: En [c](/questions/tagged/c) (y en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) se marca el final de las cadenas de caracteres con un valor especial conocido como "*terminador nulo*" que corresponde con el valor cero (`0`).
- **[Comportamiento no definido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido)**: Cuando en el código se incumplen algunas [pre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondici%C3%B3n) o [postcondiciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondici%C3%B3n) en tiempo de ejecución puede suceder que el resultado de una operación no sea [determinístico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinismo); es decir: no se sabe lo que puede pasar.

#### Ejemplo.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo de uso usando el código de [MLStud](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72185/2742):

```
char str1[20] = "¡Hola,";
strcat(str1, " mundo!\n");
```

Tenemos una variable llamada `str1` cuya representación en memoria se parecería a esta:
[image]
Por otro lado, tenemos la instrucción `strcat(str1, " mundo!\n");` que llama a la función `strcat` pasando `str1` como primer parámetro (`dest`ino) y el literal `"mundo!\n"` como origen (`src` o source). El literal tendría un aspecto en memoria parecido a este:
[image]
Como indica el manual de la función `strcat`, se copiarán los elementos de `src` en `dest` empezando a copiar en el carácter nulo de `dest` hasta haber copiado todos los elementos de `src`:
[image]
Por lo tanto el resultado sería:
[image]
Como puedes ver en las imágenes de ejemplo, si `dest` no tiene suficiente espacio estaríamos escribiendo en RAM fuera de la memoria que nos corresponde, y si `src` no tuviera terminador nulo sucedería lo mismo ¡pues no sabríamos cuándo parar de copiar!, por otro lado si `dest` no tuviera terminador nulo ¡no sabríamos dónde empezar a copiar!.

#### Tu caso.

```
void creacion(int num){
    FILE *file;
    fopen=strcat(num,".csv");
    fclose(file);       
}
```

Esto es un disparate que ni siquiera compila. `num` es una variable de tipo `int` mientras que el primer parámetro de `strcat` es un puntero a `char`, dado que `int` ni es puntero ni es `char` eso falla al compilar.

Además, el retorno de `strcat` es un puntero a `char` y lo estás intentado almacenar en `fopen` ¡que no es una variable si no una función!, seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
void creacion(int num){
    // Bufer para guardar el nombre de archivo.
    char numero[20] = "";
    // Pasamos numero a texto.
    sprintf(numero, "%d", num);
    // Concatenamos extensión del archivo.
    strcat(numero, ".csv");
    // Abrimos archivo.
    FILE *file = fopen(numero);
    // Cerramos archivo.
    fclose(file);       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes una muy buena explicacion: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcat.

"strcat permite añadir un bloque de memoria a otro. Los dos bloques deben terminar con un carácter nulo. Como en C las cadenas de caracteres no son tipos de datos en sí mismos strcat añade una cadena a otra pasándole dos punteros a los bloques de memoria reservados. El nombre strcat es una abreviación de "string concatenate" (concatenación de cadena)."

Ejemplo (sacado del sitio que te recomendé arriba):

```
char str1[100] = "¡ Hola,";    /* 100: se reserva espacio extra */
strcat (str1, " mundo !\n");
printf (str1);
```

En tu caso, se concatena '.csv' al valor de num.