# fopen no funciona y me manda SIGSEGV en debug y otro error en compilacion normal

Tags: c, string, archivo, codeblocks, rutas

basicamente busco hacer un programa que me "adivine" las rutas en la que se encuentra el archivo que le estoy especificando,eso ya lo logre,sin embargo tambien deseo acceder a dicho archivo con todo y la ruta por lo que use fopen y coloque como variable el string con todo y la ruta,sin embargo a la hora de leer este archivo me manda diferentes errores ya sea en debug mode o compilacion normal,en debug me manda SIGSEGV y en compilacion normal namas me saca del programa.

Según en el debug,el archivo fp cuando uso fopen manda null,pero en el bin si lo crea pero a veces con el nombre cambiado en algunas letras(como basura),y finalmente el error reside en eso,de que no entiendo porque me tira null en fopen,llevo varios dias tratando de entender porque no funciona y la verdad no le veo forma,les agradeceria que gente experta como ustedes me pudieran responder,(es mi primera pregunta en este sitio) les dejo el codigo:

```
///esto es un header, que luego invoco la funcion connectToDB en el main
///pero eso no es el error sino al usar la funcion fopen
typedef struct empleado{
int ID;
char nombre[30];
char apellido[30];
char sexo;//Masculino Femenino //m, f
int antiguedad;
char estadoCivil [13];//casado soltero viudo divorciado //c,s,v,d
int hijosEstudiando;
int horasTrabajadas;
int bonoLibros;
float aumento;
float sueldo;
float valeDespensa;
}Empleado;
///en el main ya habia declarado un empleado,y ese pase de parametro mas 
 //adelante
char* getCurrentDirectory(char* fileName){
// Get the current working directory:
char* buffer;

if( (buffer = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
  perror( "_getcwd error" );

else{
strcat(buffer,"\\");
strcat(buffer,fileName);
printf( "%s \nLength: %d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
return buffer;
}
void resetBuffer(char* buffer){
memset(buffer,0,strlen(buffer));
 }

 int connectToDB(Empleado registro[]){
 FILE *fp;
 FILE *bfp;
 int i=0,flag=1;
 char* path;
 path=getCurrentDirectory("DataSystem Empleados.txt");
 perror( "_buffer error?");//sends invalid argument
 printf("\nBREAKPOINT\n");

 if( (fp = fopen(path,"r"))==NULL ){
  printf("file wasnt read\n");
 }
 else{
  printf("file read succesfuly\n");
 }
  resetBuffer(path);

  path=getCurrentDirectory("DataSystem Empleados.bin");
  perror( "_buffer error?");
  printf("\nBREAKPOINT\n");

  if( (bfp = fopen(path,"w+"))==NULL ){
   printf("file wasnt created\n");
   }
  else{
     printf("file created succesfully\n");
   }
    perror( "_buffer error?");
    printf("\nBREAKPOINT\n");

    fclose(bfp);
    bfp=fopen(path,"ab+");
    resetBuffer(path);

 if(fp==NULL || bfp==NULL ){//a veces hasta aqui llega el programa o entra
perror("Error: ");
printf("\n\nDB connection failed\n");
  return(-1);
 }
 else{
 flag=0;
   char auxEC[13];
  while(1){
       printf("%d\n",i+1);
       fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %c %d %s %d %d",
       &(registro[i].ID),
       (registro[i].nombre),
       (registro[i].apellido),
       &(registro[i].sexo),
       &(registro[i].antiguedad),
       (registro[i].estadoCivil),
       &(registro[i].hijosEstudiando),
       &(registro[i].horasTrabajadas));
       /// aqui no importa solo es validacion de campos del struct 
       registro[i].sexo=validateSexo(registro[i].sexo);
       strcpy(auxEC,registro[i].estadoCivil);
       strcpy(registro[i].estadoCivil,validateEstadoCivil(auxEC));
       registro[i].sueldo=calcSueldo(registro,i);

    fwrite(registro,sizeof(Empleado),1,bfp);///escribir en binario
    i++;
      if(feof(fp)) {
         break;
      }
   }
 }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(bfp);
if (flag ==0)
  printf("\nConexion establecida,se han leido los datos del DB...%d\n\n",i);
  return i;
}
```

error en debug mode
[image: error en debug mode]
error con compilacion normal
[image: error con compilacion normal]

Comment: olvide mencionar que mi sistema operativo es windows 8.1

Comment: Deberías de echarle un ojo a [strcat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcat). Sobre todo, la parte donde dice `strcat puede ser peligroso porque ...`.

Comment: cheque como cambian los valores en el debug mode y no veo que la direccion de memoria cambie al entrar a la funcion,solo lo hace al cambiarle de nombre por ejemplo cuando le puse .bin pero en consola me imprime bien las rutas,asi que no parece ser eso....aun asi gracias

Comment: Insisto: [Uso de la función strcat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/72292/23371).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos con esta llamada:

```
if( (buffer = _getcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
```

Según la documentación de [_getcwd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sf98bd4y.aspx):

> se asigna automáticamente un búfer con un tamaño mínimo de maxlen (más solo en caso necesario) mediante malloc, para almacenar la ruta de acceso. Este búfer se puede liberar más adelante llamando a free y pasando el valor devuelto de _getcwd (un puntero al búfer asignado).

Y también:

> La función buffer puede ser NULL; se asigna automáticamente un búfer con un tamaño mínimo de maxlen (más solo en caso necesario) mediante malloc, para almacenar la ruta de acceso.

Por simplificar, si la función recibe un puntero nulo hará una reserva mínima necesaria para poder almacenar la ruta... ni un byte más. Bien, ahora haces:

```
strcat(buffer,"\\");
strcat(buffer,fileName);
```

Lo que hace `strcat` es añadir caracteres al buffer anterior, que recordemos que **ya está lleno**. `strcat` no se complica la vida. No conoce el tamaño del buffer y no se preocupa por ello... tu le dices que concatene algo y el lo hace... lo que sucede es que al salirte de la memoria que tienes asignada el Sistema Operativo detecta el problema y mata el proceso porque a los SO actuales no les gusta que un proceso se dedique a corromper memoria que no le pertenece.

Lo que tienes que hacer es forzar una reserva de memoria mayor para evitar salirte del buffer que tienes asignado.

Una posible solución, para entenderlo mejor, pasaría por crear un buffer más grande para que entren los nuevos caracteres:

```
// suponemos que el nombre del fichero no tendrá más de 98 caracteres
buffer = realloc(buffer,strlen(buffer) + 100);
if( !buffer ) // La nueva reserva puede fallar
  // ...

strcat(buffer,"\\");
strcat(buffer,fileName);
```